# Checking metadata of Amazon S3 file using iOS AWS SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the AWS iOS SDK v2, and Swift 1.2.

I am storing my app's `app.json` file on S3 and want to check it at launch to see if it's been updated since the last run. According to research, simply doing a HEAD request on the object should return the "Last-Modified" attribute which can then be compared to the previous.

The problem is that doing a HEAD request on an Object doesn't really seem to be well documented. I've got the following:

```
var metaDataRequest = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()
metaDataRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
metaDataRequest.key = S3AppJSONKey
```

This seems like a decent start, however I cannot find a way to execute the request. The `AWSS3TransferManager` has a `download()` method, but the method requires an `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` type, which an `AWSS3HeadObjectRequest` cannot be cast as.

Not sure where to go from here, short of just doing the request outside of the SDK. I did, however, want to leverage as much of the SDK as possible, so if this is possible I would love to know how.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `AWSS3` (instead of `AWSS3TransferManager`) to call [`- headObject:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/headObject:).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call headobject method of AWSS3

```
     var request = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()

    request.bucket = "flkasdhflhad"
    request.key = "hfsdahfjkhadjkshf"

   request.ifModifiedSince = NSDate()


  var s3 = AWSS3.defaultS3()

    s3.headObject(request) { ( output1 : AWSS3HeadObjectOutput?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
   print( output1?.description())
    }
```

if your object is modified from specified date then it will return u the object otherwise it will return u the status code 304.

Comment: Can we get an Obj-C example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following Swift 2.2 method to check if file exist or not

```
func checkIfFileExist() {
    let s3 = AWSS3.defaultS3()
    let headObjectsRequest = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()
    headObjectsRequest.bucket = "YourBucketName" //Don't add "/" at end of your bucket Name    

    headObjectsRequest.key = "YourFileNameYouWantToCheckFor" //Don't add "/" in start of file name 

    s3.headObject(headObjectsRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error to find file: \(error)")

        } else {
            print("fileExist")
        }
    }

}
```

Note: Example to set bucket and key

suppose you have bucket named "ABC" and than folder named "XYZ" and than inside "XYZ" you have file "abc123"

than write

headObjectsRequest.bucket = "ABC/XYZ"

and

headObjectsRequest.key = "abc123"

and if you want to check for the entire folder

than use

headObjectsRequest.bucket = "ABC/XYZ"

and

headObjectsRequest.key = ""

Thanks Mohsin