# When requesting metadata of Amazon S3 file using iOS Swift 3 & AWS SDK 2.5, OSStatus error, Security Error has occurred

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS SDK 2.5 and Swift 3.  Having gotten S3 to work in Android, I'm transitioning to iOS and Swift.

After following the solution in another StackOverflow question [Checking metadata of Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541725/checking-metadata-of-amazon-s3-file-using-ios-aws-sdk-in-swift), I receive an OSStatus error [-34018] Security error has occurred.

Here's the code snippet based on that solution.

```
let request = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()
request!.bucket = bucketName
request!.key = key

let s3 = AWSS3.default()
s3.headObject(request!) {
    (output1 : AWSS3HeadObjectOutput?, error : Error?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("Error: could not find file \(error)")
    } else {
        print (output1?.lastModified! ?? "")
    }
}
```

I have a valid Cognito pool ID, bucket and key.  I'm not sure what the issue is.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled keychain access in your app?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of keychain access before.  I didn't have to worry about this for Android, but it sounds like this is necessary for iOS.  How do I enable keychain access?  Is there a link describing how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apple changed how the keychain is accessed in ios10.  The workaround is to enable the keychain sharing entitlement in capabilities.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It solved the Security error I was getting, but still having problems trying to get the metadata of the object stored on Amazon S3.  I don't know if anyone else has had these issues, but I moving to Firebase storage since their sample code works.  I'm a bit disappointed that Amazon posts sample code that doesn't work.

Comment: if you can give me more information on the metadata issue i can help. Maybe on a separate post though or on https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable keychain capability in your XCode project. Apple changed the way how keychain is accessed on iOS10. for more information please see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html