# AWS S3 HeadObject Can't Resolve Dispatch_Once

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using [this other SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541725/checking-metadata-of-amazon-s3-file-using-ios-aws-sdk-in-swift) I was able to determine how best to determine if an object was already in my S3 bucket. However, my code seems to be out of whack and I am not familiar with AWS errors.

For starters, I know my AWS works as I already have code that accesses the bucket.

```
static func uploadData(data:Data, progressHandler: @escaping (_ progress:Progress) -> Void, completionHandlerFunction: @escaping () -> Void, DBKey:String) {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = { (task, progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            progressHandler(progress)
        })
    }

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            completionHandlerFunction()
            if(error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                print(task.response!)
            }
        })
    }

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

    transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                               bucket: self.bucketName,
                               key: DBKey,
                               contentType: "video/mp4",
                               expression: expression,
                               completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                (task) -> AnyObject? in
                                if let error = task.error {
                                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }

                                if let _ = task.result {
                                    // Do something with uploadTask.
                                }
                                return nil;
    }
}
```

So, I attempt a similar strategy to determine if an item exists

```
static func checkForItem(item:String, foundHandler: @escaping () -> Void, notFoundHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let s3 = AWSS3.default()

    let request = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()
    request!.bucket = Storage.bucketName
    request!.key = item

    s3.headObject(request!).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            notFoundHandler()
        }
        else {
            foundHandler()
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

It seems, however, the moment I get past `let s3 = AWSS3.default()`, it goes into [image: Error]

Any approach on to why `AWSS3.default()` would provide this situation? I'm not even accessing my bucket yet or any critical information. My Cocoapods are up to date (just ran them) but I'm willing to try anything to get it working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Amazon Web Service's [Mobile Hub](https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home), I downloaded my `awsconfiguration.json` and stuck it in my app.

```
{
    "UserAgent": "MobileHub/1.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "MyPoolID",
                "Region": "MyRegion"
            }
        }
    },
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "S3TransferUtility": {
        "Default": {
            "Bucket": "MyBucket",
            "Region": "MyRegion"
        }
    },
    "DynamoDBObjectMapper": {
        "Default": {
            "Region": "MyRegion"
        }
    },
    "PinpointAnalytics": {
        "Default": {
            "AppId": "myAppId",
            "Region": "MyRegion"
        }
    },
    "PinpointTargeting": {
        "Default": {
            "Region": "MyRegion"
        }
    },
    "UserFileManager": {
        "Default": {
            "Bucket": "MyBucket",
            "Region": "MyRegion"
        }
    },
}
```

However, I didn't have the `S3` portion. It didn't come from the [Mobile Hub](https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home), so I decided to edit it and see if it worked and it did! I added this,

```
"S3": {
    "Default": {
        "Bucket": "MyBucket",
        "Region": "MyRegion"
    }
}
```

to the bottom of the json and it worked!

For anyone else who has Amazon issues, make sure you have all your aws files configured appropriately!